# Do English speakers accept the word "ostarthritis"?

Tags: word-meaning, spelling

I find the word ostarthritis [here](http://cn.bing.com/dict/search?q=ostarthritis&go=%E6%90%9C%E7%B4%A2&qs=n&form=Z9LH5&pq=ostarthritis&sc=1-12&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=5D1AB0CD78AC4032B04FB87496FC6368), but when I check the word on www.dictionary.com and some other online dictionary, it seems that this word is not correct and can not be found? Do you guys know this word?

Comment: The link doesn't work for me. However, when I searched it, I got this instead: [osteoarthritis](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/osteoarthritis).

Comment: Could you quote the relevant portion of the text you found in your question?

Comment: @user3169 Oh, it's there all right, at the included link. It reads: "No results found for ostarthritis." *sigh*

Comment: @HenryWang The link you provide, to the search engine _bing,_ informs us that the word is not found. Google does a little better: it returns a link to _this question!_ This is becoming far too Gödelian for my taste.

Answer (score 5):

*Ostarthritis* is an obscure variant of the condition more commonly known as *[osteoarthritis](http://www.niams.nih.gov/health_info/osteoarthritis/)*. There is [an entry](https://books.google.com/books?id=9RWCAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA350&lpg=PA350), for example, in *A Thesaurus of Medical Word Roots* by Horace Gerald Danner (Scarecrow Press, 2013):

> Leading root compoud: ost:
>   ostarthritis (or, osteoarthritis) (*athron* joint + *itis* inflammation)

But it neither makes an appearance in the Oxford English Dictionary, nor in Google Ngrams, suggesting *ostarthritis* is not in common usage among most English speakers.

The vast majority of Google search results turn up *ostarthritis* in non-English sources— German (from both Germany and Austria), Korean, Chinese, Dutch, and Indonesian in my results— so it may be the preferred term in other languages, or it may be a case of an old variant making its way into translation dictionaries and, being rarely used, never being revisited.

Comment: Marvelous research! and +1. My own searches were cursory and dead-ended at Baidu.

Comment: Found a contemporary English-language reference [here](http://www.pubpdf.com/pub/24818492/Effects-of-acupotomy-electroacupuncture-or-round-sharp-acupuncture-needle-interventions-on-expressio). Others indicate that it is still widely used, but only in Asian medical literature, alternatively with _osteoarthritis._